# How to Convert a variable to a constant

Tags: android

I am new to android & java. This might be very simple but I'm stuck... I am creating an app where by clicking on an "add" button a square is added in some default position on a canvas. You can then move and resize the square. Once you finish moving/ reshaping, my intention is for the square to maintain its new size/ position and for the user to be able to click on the add button where a new square will appear in the original default position. You can then again move / reshape the second square. And eventually add as many squares as you like (each unique).

I have managed to add the first square and i am also able to move/ reshape. I also created an array list to store the squares. My issue is that as soon as i add the second square, the shape and position of the first square are reset to the default position and size. And if i move the second square, so does the first one. So effectively its as if i end up with a stacked set of squares that all move and reshape at the same time.

The question is, how do i convert the variable information of position/ size to a constant before i add the square to the array?
I have the following in my main activity

```
addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(addTimer != null) {
                    addTimer.cancel();
                }
                if (addclickcount>0) {
                    addBoxtoList();
                }
                addBox();
                addclickcount++;
            }


           });
    public void addBox(){ mCustomView.drawRoundRect();}
    public void addBoxtoList(){mCustomView.addBoxtoList();}
```

Then in CustomView

```
    public class CustomView extends View {

    private ArrayList<Box> boxesArray = new ArrayList<>();

    private RectF mRectSquare;
    private Paint mPaintSquare;

    private static RectF aRectSquare;
    private static Paint aPaintSquare;

    private int mSquareLeft, mSquareTop, dx, dy;

    int colorSelected;


    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        init(null);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        init(attrs);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(attrs);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(attrs);
    }

    private void init (@Nullable AttributeSet set){
        mRectSquare = new RectF();
        mPaintSquare = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaintSquare.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        mPaintSquare.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        mPaintSquare.setAlpha(85);

    }

    
    public void drawRoundRect(){
           if (General.addBoxCheck == true) {
               dx = 200;
               dy = 200;
               mSquareLeft = scrwd - dx - 50;
               mSquareTop = 50;
               General.addBoxCheck = false;
           }

           mRectSquare.left = mSquareLeft;
           mRectSquare.top = mSquareTop;
           mRectSquare.right = mRectSquare.left + dx;
           mRectSquare.bottom = mRectSquare.top + dy;
           
        postInvalidate();
    }

    public void addBoxtoList(){

        boxid = boxesArray.size() + 1;
        aRectSquare = mRectSquare;
        aPaintSquare = mPaintSquare;
        Box boxa = new Box(boxid, aRectSquare, aPaintSquare);
        boxesArray.add(boxa);

        //postInvalidate();
        }


   @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.drawRoundRect(mRectSquare, 15, 15, mPaintSquare);

       if(boxesArray != null) {
           RectF rectF = new RectF();
           Paint paint = new Paint();

           for (int i = 0; i < boxesArray.size(); i++) {
               paint = boxesArray.get(i).getPaint();
               rectF = boxesArray.get(i).getRect();
               

               canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, 15, 15, paint);
           }
                    }
       super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        boolean value = super.onTouchEvent(event);

        switch (event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:{
                return true;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:{
                int x = (int) event.getX();
                int y = (int) event.getY();

                    mSquareLeft = x;
                    mSquareTop = y;

                    postInvalidate();
                    return value;
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure what your question means to be honest. There isn't such thing as "converting a variable to a constant". If you want it to be 'constant', don't change it?

Comment: hi thanks for the reply. I realize that being new im probably not expressing my issue clearly. I added the code. Its not that i want the variable to be constant. The coordinates of a square i add depend on the touch event. I want to somehow store the coordinates of each square. Now i seem to be adding squares to my array which all keep changing coordinates based on the touch event.

Comment: Maybe try and make a [mre] so we can see your problem clearly?

Comment: does it make sense now?

Answer (score -1):

The question seems quite vague, if the values are changing then it means that **you** changed the values. If you don’t change the values of the array then essentially it should be a "constant". My assumption is that you are overwriting the array and therefore the value is changing. It would help to see your code.

Check the index of the stored square shapes and verify that you're not overwriting on any of the previous indexes.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply. I added the code. so even though i moved a square and added it to the array, the square coordinates and size keep updating based on the touch event. I hope this makes my issue clearer.